# coordinating in 2D array & express them in div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multidimensional-array

Allrighty, idea goes something like this ~ You click the middle button/wherever but you want to turn on "left + right + up & down" buttons

```
     *   *   *   *   *
     *   *   3   *   *         // "2" is where you click
     *   3   2   3   *         // "3"s are where you want the results to be shown
     *   *   3   *   *
     *   *   *   *   *

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    var selectionDiv = document.getElementById('MySecondDiv');

    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length;i++)
    {
       if(divs[i] == selectionDiv)
       {
         var previous = divs[i - 1];
         var next = divs[i + 1];
    }
```

This is what I've done so far but it only works for sides.
Anybody?! I couldn't figure out where to start at all...
Thank you

Comment: here is an example for my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvvXLB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the `.offset().left` and `.offset().top` values. Add the following to your code.

### Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/LEEwYj)

```
var clicked = $(this);
var up;
var down;

$('div').each(function() {
  if (($(this).offset().top - clicked.offset().top == 103) &&
    ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
    up = $(this);
  }
  if ((clicked.offset().top - $(this).offset().top == 103) &&
    ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
    down = $(this);
  }
});
up.fadeTo(220, 0.4);
up.fadeTo(220, 1);
down.fadeTo(220, 0.4);
down.fadeTo(220, 1);
$('div').each(function() {
  if (($(this).offset().top - clicked.offset().top == 206) &&
    ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
    up = $(this);
  }
  if ((clicked.offset().top - $(this).offset().top == 206) &&
    ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
    down = $(this);
  }
});
up.delay(200).fadeTo(220, 0.4);
up.fadeTo(220, 1);
down.delay(200).fadeTo(220, 0.4);
down.fadeTo(220, 1);
$('div').each(function() {
  if (($(this).offset().top - clicked.offset().top == 309) &&
    ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
    up = $(this);
  }
  if ((clicked.offset().top - $(this).offset().top == 309) &&
    ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
    down = $(this);
  }
});
up.delay(260).fadeTo(220, 0.4);
up.fadeTo(220, 1);
down.delay(260).fadeTo(220, 0.4);
down.fadeTo(220, 1);
```

```js
//By javxteam@gmail.com
//My first demo-project!
//Click & Enjoy!
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).fadeTo(100,0.4);  
   });
   $('div').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).fadeTo(100,1);
   });
  var currback = $('div');
  var currforw = $('div');
  $('div').click(function() {
    currback = $(this);
    currforw = $(this);
    var up;
    var down;
    var clicked = $(this);
    $(this).fadeTo(220,0.2);
    $(this).fadeTo(220,0.4);
    
    // up and down
    $('div').each(function() {
      if (($(this).offset().top - clicked.offset().top == 103) &&
          ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
        up = $(this);
      }
      if ((clicked.offset().top - $(this).offset().top == 103) &&
          ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
        down = $(this);
      }
    });
    up.fadeTo(220,0.4);
    up.fadeTo(220,1);
    down.fadeTo(220,0.4);
    down.fadeTo(220,1);
    $('div').each(function() {
      if (($(this).offset().top - clicked.offset().top == 206) &&
          ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
        up = $(this);
      }
      if ((clicked.offset().top - $(this).offset().top == 206) &&
          ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
        down = $(this);
      }
    });
    up.delay(200).fadeTo(220,0.4);
    up.fadeTo(220,1);
    down.delay(200).fadeTo(220,0.4);
    down.fadeTo(220,1);
    $('div').each(function() {
      if (($(this).offset().top - clicked.offset().top == 309) &&
          ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
        up = $(this);
      }
      if ((clicked.offset().top - $(this).offset().top == 309) &&
          ($(this).offset().left == clicked.offset().left)) {
        down = $(this);
      }
    });
    up.delay(260).fadeTo(220,0.4);
    up.fadeTo(220,1);
    down.delay(260).fadeTo(220,0.4);
    down.fadeTo(220,1);
    
    //backward
    currback = currback.prev();
    currback.fadeTo(220,0.4);
    currback.fadeTo(220,1);
    currback = currback.prev();
    currback.delay(200).fadeTo(220,0.4);
    currback.fadeTo(220,1);
    currback = currback.prev();
    currback.delay(260).fadeTo(250,0.4);
    currback.fadeTo(220,1);
    //forward
    currforw = currforw.next();
    currforw.fadeTo(220,0.4);
    currforw.fadeTo(220,1);
    currforw = currforw.next();
    currforw.delay(200).fadeTo(220,0.4);
    currforw.fadeTo(220,1);
    currforw = currforw.next();
    currforw.delay(260).fadeTo(250,0.4);
    currforw.fadeTo(220,1);
  });
});

/*var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var selectionDiv = document.getElementById('MySecondDiv');

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length;i++)
{
   if(divs[i] == selectionDiv)
   {
     var previous = divs[i - 1];
     var next = divs[i + 1];
   }
}*/
```

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. anyways.. good to know about offsets tho, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cant see the structure of the diffs, but from your code I am assuming a flat collection of them for all cells.
In which case, you will know the length of a row.

You can then have something like:

```
var up = divs[i - row_length];
var down = divs[i + row_length];
```